# merge new document with several existing pdfs

Tags: forms, pdf, import, field

I should create a new pdf , for example a offer. At the end of the new pdf i have to import several existing pdfs, these pdf has form fields and i must fill up this fields.
One problem is that the different existing PDF has all the same form fields e.g txtNAME.
Is there a possibility to add existing PDF in a open document and fill up formfields directly?

Thank for help or ideas

Comment: you can "Append" text or fields

Comment: Do the fields with the same name have to be filled differently? Or shall they contain the same value?

Answer (score 0):

Just keep in mind that fields with the same name will have the same value.

This can be a boon (if you did some thinking ahead when you planned the forms), but it also can be a hindrance.

One possibility you may have, if the number different additional pages is not too high: You might prepare a "master form", which contains the subsequent pages as hidden Templates, and then when you create your document, you will spawn the according pages with the option to make unique field names.